# apacheが自身のパソコンにいくつインストールされているかの確認方法の方法が知りたい

Tags: apache, mamp

追記1：mampをインストール済み。
追記2：portscanコマンドの送信を開始しました…

Port Scanning host: 127.0.0.1

```
 Open TCP Port:     88          kerberos
 Open TCP Port:     445         microsoft-ds
 Open TCP Port:     631         ipp
 Open TCP Port:     3306        mysql
 Open TCP Port:     49157
portscanコマンドの送信を完了しました…
```

以下、自分なりにターミナルにコマンドを打ち、apacheの状態を確認しました。
下記の場合は、以下の三点がインストールされているという事なのでしょうか。

```
/usr/sbin/httpd
/usr/share/httpd
/Library/WebServer/share/httpd
```

```
■■■■iMac:~ ■■■■$ sudo find / -name httpd
/usr/sbin/httpd
/usr/share/httpd
/Library/WebServer/share/httpd
/Users/tanakaakio/Desktop/Library/bin/httpd
/Applications/MAMP/Library/bin/httpd
```

```
■■■■iMac:~ ■■■■$ find / -type f -name httpd -print
/usr/sbin/httpd
/Users/tanakaakio/Desktop/Library/bin/httpd
/Applications/MAMP/Library/bin/httpd
```

Comment: いわゆる `http` サーバーは apache httpd 以外にもいっぱいあります `nginx` とか。それに１つの製品が２か所以上に symlink 張っているだけかもしれませんし、その調査方法ではなんとも判断できないです。方針変更することをお勧めします。

Comment: 方針変更します。```$ sudo find / -name httpd```と```$ find / -type f -name httpd -print```以外でオススメの調査コマンドなどございますか。

Comment: @アフロ 関連質問でMAMP環境を入れているという話ですので、それらの情報もあらかじめ質問文に含めた方が親切だと思います。

Comment: ありがとうございます。追記いたします。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

macOS は OS 標準のパッケージマネージャのようなものがないので、確実に調べるには、既にやられているように`find`コマンドなどで探し出すしかない気がします。

提示されている情報を見た限り、

- macOS 標準添付の Apache
- MAMP 添付の Apache

の2つが入っているようです。

```
/usr/sbin/httpd
/usr/share/httpd
/Library/WebServer/share/httpd
```

この3つはどれもOS標準添付Apacheのファイルです。1つ目が実行ファイル、2つ目が実行時に使われるデータファイル、3つ目がマニュアルです。